# How does @pytest.mark.filterwarnings work?

Tags: python, pytest

According to [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#pytest-mark-filterwarnings) you can ignore warnings like this:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore:api v1")
def test_foo():
```

which gives:

But there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this mini-language (*is* it even a minilanguage?)

How is the match done?

I'm asking this because the following test doesn't ignore the `DeprecationWarning` raised by importing `boto3`:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore:DeprecationWarning")
def test_ignore_warnings():
    import boto3
```

Pytest outputs:

```
============================================================================================================================== warnings summary ===============================================================================================================================
/home/rob/dev/time-series/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py:624
  /home/rob/dev/time-series/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py:624: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
    class HeadersDict(collections.MutableMapping):

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
==================================================================================================================== 1 passed, 1 warnings in 0.36 seconds =====================================================================================================================
```

Comment: Looking at the doc `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore:api v1")` seems to be mapping to `warnings.warn(UserWarning("api v1, should use functions from v2"))`. Perhaps, it is to ignore the warnings that contain "api v1"?

Comment: I've opened a PR to clarify this but that is exactly right @shahkalpesh https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/9464

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The filters work the same way as when you use `-W` argument with `python` command (see `python --help`). The format is described in the documentation of the [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters) module. In short it's `action:message:category:module:line` where `action` is probably mandatory but the other parts can be omitted.

`"ignore:api v1"` would try to match the `message` by defining *"a string containing a regular expression that the start of the warning message must match"*. Since you actually want to match `category` you can skip `message`. This means that you just seem to be missing one colon after `ignore` so this is the correct format:

```py
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore::DeprecationWarning")
def test_ignore_warnings():
    import boto3
```

However, **you might apparently still get the warning if it happens during an import of a package** outside of a test function. In this case you might need to specify the filter globally as a pytest's argument:

`pytest -W "ignore::DeprecationWarning" ./tests/`

...or add it to *pytest.ini*:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

If such a global exclusion is undesirable, you can try to limit it to a particular module:

`ignore::DeprecationWarning:boto3`

#### Testing

For testing purposes, you can use the following code:

```py
import warnings

def something():
    warnings.warn("Test", DeprecationWarning)

@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore::DeprecationWarning")
def test_ignore_warnings():
    something()
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't ignore the warning. There's something else going on I think...

Comment: @LondonRob That's strange because I actually tested it. See the additional code.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour I see? (You'll need to `pip install boto3`)

Comment: @LondonRob Which version do you have? With boto3==1.10.6 I don't get the warning even without the filter.

Comment: I've got 1.10.6 too! Pytest 5.0.1 and Python 3.7.1

Comment: No idea. I have Python 3.7.4 though.

Comment: @LondonRob I've just run into the issue myself with a different package. It seems that if it happens during import, it might not be possible to suppress it with a decorator but it can be done with a CLI param (see my updated answer). Any chance that in your case *boto3* was being also imported somewhere out of the `test_ignore_warnings()` function? That would explain why I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: Yes! I think you might be right! Well debugged. The script containing the test I showed also imports stuff which uses `boto3`. In fact, importing something inside a test is probably pretty unusual, but I did it here to make my MWE concise. Gah!

Comment: @LondonRob: Importing something inside a test is **what you should always be doing,** for this and similar reasons. There's nothing unusual about that; that's standard practice. Importing something *outside* a test is what's unusual. All imports other than from `pytest` itself should be considered suspect and confined to the specific tests requiring those imports.

Comment: @CecilCurry That's really interesting. I've always felt a bit dirty doing imports inside my test functions, but your justification makes complete sense and clears things up nicely for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is not standard at all @CecilCurry. AFAIK, no big python package is doing this. Still an interesting take.

Comment: A possible explanation is if you store or run the tests from the same directory as your function, then it counts your function's imorts and the test's imports as well - I ran into the same issue (this time it was botocore). 
Adding the decorator reduced the warning count from 9 to 4, adding the ignore flag on the command line suppressed it entirely.